# How can I map attributes into dictionary of lists in Ansible

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

With the following json:

```json
msg: [
  {
    "name": "Primary_colors",
    "sub_attrs": [
        {
            "name": "Red",
        },
        {
            "name": "Blue",
        },
        {
            "name": "Yellow",
        }
    ],
    
  },
  {
    "name": "Secondary_colors",
    "sub_attrs": [
        {
            "name": "Green",
        },
        {
            "name": "Orange",
        },
        {
            "name": "Purple",
        }
    ],  
  }
]
```

Using Ansible how can I map the names of each color type to make it a dictionary key and make the name attribute of sub_attrs the value as a list of each

I've been able to extract the data I want but I can't figure out how to make the types_of_colors the key and map the names from the sub_attrs which should be a list to the correct color type

```yaml
- name: Set facts
  set_fact:
    types_of_colors: '{{ msg | map(attribute='name') | list }}' 
    names_of_colors: '{{ msg | map(attribute='sub_attrs') | sum(start=[]) | map(attribute='name') | list }}'
```

How can I make the types of colors the key and group the names_of_colors based on the types into a list and convert it into a dictionary

Expected result data structure:

```yaml
Primary_colors:
  - Red
  - Blue
  - Yellow
Secondary_colors:
  - Green
  - Orange
  - Purple
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear because you're not being consistent about what data structure you expect. Your top level data structure in your first example is a list, but in the second it's a dictionary. Which one do you want? Ideally, edit the question for clarity rather than answering in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the key names from the dict list:

```yaml
my_keys: {{ msg | map(attribute='name' }}
```

This gives:

```json
"my_keys": [
    "Primary_colors",
    "Secondary_colors"
]
```

Extract the list of `sub_attrs` and transform them to a list of lists:

```yaml
my_values: "{{ msg | map(attribute='sub_attrs') | map('map', attribute='name') }}"
```

This gives:

```json
"my_values": [
    [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ],
    [
        "Green",
        "Orange",
        "Purple"
    ]
]
```

At this points, we have two synchronized lists with keys on one side and values on the other. Rearrange keys and values together in the expected result dict:

```yaml
my_colors_dict: "{{ my_keys | zip(my_values) | community.general.dict }}"
# or using python's `dict()` directly
my_colors_dict: "{{ dict(my_keys | zip(my_values)) }}"
```

Both expressions are equivalent and give:

```json
"my_colors_dict": {
    "Primary_colors": [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ],
    "Secondary_colors": [
        "Green",
        "Orange",
        "Purple"
    ]
}
```

You can test the above with the following complete playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Transform data demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    msg: [
      {
        "name": "Primary_colors",
        "sub_attrs": [
          {
            "name": "Red",
          },
          {
            "name": "Blue",
          },
          {
            "name": "Yellow",
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        "name": "Secondary_colors",
        "sub_attrs": [
          {
            "name": "Green",
          },
          {
            "name": "Orange",
          },
          {
            "name": "Purple",
          }
        ],
      }
    ]

    my_keys: "{{ msg | map(attribute='name') }}"
    my_values: "{{ msg | map(attribute='sub_attrs') | map('map', attribute='name') }}"
    my_colors_dict: "{{ my_keys | zip(my_values) | community.general.dict }}"
    # Alternative syntax whith python's `dict()`
    # my_colors_dict: "{{ dict(my_keys | zip(my_values)) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show extracted list of keys
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_keys

    - name: Show the extracted and reworked list of values
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_values

    - name: Show the result dict
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_colors_dict
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I'm looking for. I wasn't aware you could map the map filter like that.

Is there a way to do it without using the community.general.dict filter?

Comment: Updated the answer with alternative syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter *json_query* to get the keys and values. Then
use the filter *items2dict*. For example,

```yaml
  colors: "{{ msg|
              json_query('[].{key: name, value: sub_attrs[].name}')|
              items2dict }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  colors:
    Primary_colors:
    - Red
    - Blue
    - Yellow
    Secondary_colors:
    - Green
    - Orange
    - Purple
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    msg:
      - name: Primary_colors
        sub_attrs:
        - name: Red
        - name: Blue
        - name: Yellow
      - name: Secondary_colors
        sub_attrs:
        - name: Green
        - name: Orange
        - name: Purple

    colors: "{{ msg|
                json_query('[].{key: name, value: sub_attrs[].name}')|
                items2dict }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: colors
```